# How to use a solar panel that has 'watts' to power a battery charger that requires: 3v & 2.8 amps?

Tags: voltage, batteries, solar-cell, charger, watts

I have a battery charger that charges small batteries ( AAA & AA ).
It uses an adapter that gives it 3V and 2.8 amps.

I want to remove the adapter and give it solar energy instead.
There are cheap solar panels out there (small ones) but based on what I see, solar panels only output "watts" for example "5 watts".

What am I supposed to do with "Watts" if what I need is 3 Volts and 2.8 amps ?

Comment: Can you post a link to the particular solar panels you are thinking about using?

Comment: there are tiny things on amazon such as this : http://www.amazon.com/Sunforce-50013-Motorcycle-Powersports-Battery/dp/B001D6GYLO/ref=pd_sim_auto_2 but there are bigger versions of it as well that output more watts. the battery charger i am using is this : http://www.amazon.com/La-Crosse-Technology-Battery-Charger/dp/B000RSOV50/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1379564193&sr=8-1&keywords=battery+charger+la+crosse

Comment: There is also this with more watts. : http://www.amazon.com/Schumacher-SP-200-Solar-Battery-Maintainer/dp/B004ZC3TFC/ref=pd_sim_auto_12

Comment: Is there some sort of a product out there that can convert watts to specific amount of volts and amps, so the output can satisfy the device in a exact manner ? such as this : http://www.amazon.com/Elenco-Variable-Voltage-Power-Supply/dp/B0002D0ROO/ref=sr_1_8?ie=UTF8&qid=1379563355&sr=8-8&keywords=variac

Comment: it looks like there might be a car cigarette lighter adapter that people are using for this specific battery charger : http://www.ebay.com/itm/Car-Adapter-for-AccuPower-IQ328-also-La-Crosse-BC-700-BC-900-BC-9009-BC-1000-/230780742434?pt=Battery_Chargers&hash=item35bb9aab22#ht_14756wt_887 the output i think is 3v and 4 amps while the battery charger requires only 2.8 AMPS, i suppose people are okay with 4 amps and perhaps it does not damage the battery charger ?  perhaps this cigarette lighter can be connected to a solar panel that outputs 12volts ?

Comment: Solar panels have voltage and Ampere ratings. Check them out. They're usually the maximum output values. And then you have the maximum output power, which is the "Watts".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a few things to consider here.

Firstly some theory though. You mention watts, voltage and amperage in your question. These are all different but related. Watts are a measure of power. Voltage and amperage (or better: current) go hand-in hand, like water pressure and flow.
Now for your charger you need a supple that provides 3 volts at 2.8 amps. The voltage will be constant, the current (amps) it draws will probably depend on the amount of batteries your charging - 2.8A is the maximum.
The relation between watts (P for power), voltage (V) and current (A for amps) is simple: 
$$P=V \times A$$
So for your battery charger you need to provide at least 3Vx2.8A = 8.4W of power.

Now don't assume you can 'just' use a 8.4W or larger solar panel. The charger needs a constant 3V. A solar panel's voltage depends on two things: the amount of sunlight, and the 'load' - or how much current is drawn from the panel by whatever you connect to this.

Unfortunately, this relation is not constant, and to achieve the maximum power from the panel you need some device the 'regulates' the load and then provides a constant voltage to your device. This type of devices are available 'off the shelf' as 'solar power supply' or 'solar regulator'.